# Very strange connection times in Linux

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

I create a listening socket with backlog 1, and the connect 64 sockets to it.

**socket.c**

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L

#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/time.h> 
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    int server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in server_address = {0};
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server_address.sin_port = htons(8000); 
    bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&server_address, sizeof(server_address)); 
    if (listen(server_socket, 1) == 0) {
        printf("Listening\n");
    } else {
        printf("Failed to listen\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        int client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        struct timespec start;
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
        if (connect(client_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&server_address, sizeof(server_address)) == 0) {
            struct timespec end;
            clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
            double elapsed = end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec + (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1e9;
            printf("Connected socket #%d in %.3lfs\n", i, elapsed);
        } else {
            printf("Failed to connect socket #%d\n", i);
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
$ gcc -o socket -std=c99 socket.c
$ ./socket
Listening
Connected socket #0 in 0.000s
Connected socket #1 in 0.000s
Connected socket #2 in 0.000s
Connected socket #3 in 0.000s
Connected socket #4 in 1.000s
Connected socket #5 in 0.000s
Connected socket #6 in 3.004s
Connected socket #7 in 0.000s
Connected socket #8 in 3.004s
Connected socket #9 in 0.000s
Connected socket #10 in 3.004s
Connected socket #11 in 0.000s
Connected socket #12 in 3.004s
Connected socket #13 in 0.000s
Connected socket #14 in 3.004s
Connected socket #15 in 0.000s
Connected socket #16 in 3.004s
Connected socket #17 in 0.000s
...
```

The first four connections are instantaneous, the fifth takes 1 second, and then connections oscillate between 0 and 3 seconds until all sockets connect and the program exits. This behavior is 100% repeatable.

I've read extensively about TCP connections, the Linux networking documentation, and [other resources](http://veithen.github.io/2014/01/01/how-tcp-backlog-works-in-linux.html).

But I still cannot explain what is happening.

**Why are connection times varying so wildly?**

---

**System info**

```
$ uname -a
Linux paul 3.19.0-51-generic #58~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 26 22:02:58 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

(`/etc/sysctl.conf` is empty.)

Comment: Anything changes if you `connect()` to a real IP like `127.0.0.1` instead of `INADDT_ANY`? If you actually `accept()` the incoming connections?

Answer (score 1):

The docs for [listen](http://www.man-online.org/page/2-listen/) explain this, "if the underlying protocol supports retransmission, the request may be ignored so that a later reattempt at connection succeeds". If you raise the backlog, you'll see that the point at which the delays start changes.

Comment: Okay. But where the first 4 fast? And why is only every other connection? What timeouts or settings are causing the long connection times? I'm looking for understand Linux TCP beyond "make this number high enough, and something else will happen".

Comment: @PaulDraper It's a race condition. There's one piece of code that's adding to the listen queue and once piece of code that's draining the listen queue. If the connect happens to occur while there's room in the listen queue, it completes immediately. If not, it's delayed until there's a retransmission.

Comment: The alternation occurs because you wait for one connection to complete before you try the next. So a connection that has to wait will almost always leave the listen queue empty for the next attempt.

Answer (score 1):

As David Schwartz mentioned, it is due to your backlog. TCP code which processes SYN request considers accept queue being full and also SYN queue.
As seen [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c?v=3.16#L1287)

```
1287         /* Accept backlog is full. If we have already queued enough
1288          * of warm entries in syn queue, drop request. It is better than
1289          * clogging syn queue with openreqs with exponentially increasing
1290          * timeout.
1291          */
1292         if (sk_acceptq_is_full(sk) && inet_csk_reqsk_queue_young(sk) > 1) {
1293                 NET_INC_STATS_BH(sock_net(sk), LINUX_MIB_LISTENOVERFLOWS);
1294                 goto drop;
1295         }
```

Once above condition is reached, your SYN packets are being dropped. Client's retransmission happen after 3 seconds (initial SYN), which get's accepted

You won't see any delay with connect, if you set backlog to 65